# pandas create a boolean column based on multiple conditions on another column for each group

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following `df`,

```
cluster_id   inv_id    
1            A1
1            A1
2            A1111A
2            A1111A
```

I want to `groupby` `cluster_id` and create a column called `invalid_inv_id`, based on two conditions on `inv_id`:

```
1. in each cluster, if the length of inv_id (stripped of non numerics) < 100 set "invalid_inv_id" to true;
```

or

```
2. in each cluster, if the length of inv_id is < 3 set "invalid_inv_id" to true.
```

the code is like,

```
df['inv_id_stp'] = df.inv_id.str.replace(r'\D+', '')

grouped = df.groupby('cluster_id')

invoices['invalid_inv_id'] = grouped['inv_id_stp'].transform(lambda x: x.str.len()) < 100

invoices['invalid_inv_id'] = grouped['inv_id'].transform(lambda x: x.str.len()) < 3
```

I am wondering how to make the two conditions into one line of code, so the result will look like,

```
cluster_id    inv_id    invalid_inv_id
1             A1         True
1             A1         True
2             A1111A     True
2             A1111A     True
```

Comment: I do not think you need <3 this condition

Comment: It is best to create a sample set that generates both True and False results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, `groupby` is no needed here

```
(df.inv_id.str.len()<3)|(df.inv_id.str.replace(r'\D+', '').str.len()<100)
Out[472]: 
0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
Name: inv_id, dtype: bool
```

Since need `any`

```
((df.inv_id.str.len()<3)|(df.inv_id.str.replace(r'\D+', '').str.len()<100)).groupby(df['cluster_id']).transform('any')
```

Comment: `groupby` is necessary here, coz I need to consider in terms of each cluster if the length of any `inv_id` is < 100, then set `invalid_inv_id` to true to all members of the cluster